# MySQL GROUP_CONCAT in another GROUP_CONCAT

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible at all?
What I want to get is something like this:

```
+-------------------------------+
| data 1 (another1, another2);  |
| data 2 (another1 ..... )      |
+-------------------------------+
```

From table something like this:

```
--------------------------------+
data1 | another1 | foreign key1 |
--------------------------------+
data1 | another2 | foreign key1 |
--------------------------------+
data2 | another1 | foreign key1 |
--------------------------------+
```

I use this code

```
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(data, ' (',  another, ')') SEPARATOR ';\r\n ') as InOneCell
```

and got this output:

```
+-------------------------------+
| data 1 (another1);            |
| data 1 (another2);            |
| data 2 (another1); ...        |
+-------------------------------+
```

Tried this:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(data, ' (',  GROUP_CONCAT(another SEPARATOR ', '), ')') SEPARATOR ';\r\n ') as InOneCell
```

and got error **"Invalid use of group function"**, which is really shady -_-
I do group by - foreing key due to complex query (lower).

What I do wrong or it is impossible on only SQL?

Here the full query:

```
SELECT  
s.name, 
s.surname, 
gr.number AS 'group', 
s.bitrh_date, 
s.email, 
s.registration_ip,
s.registration_time,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(dis.code, ' ', dis.title, ' (',  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT g.mark SEPARATOR ', '), ')') SEPARATOR ';\r\n ') as learning,
ROUND(AVG(g.mark), 2) AS average,
gr.semester,
ref.text AS reference

FROM t_students s
LEFT JOIN t_grades g
    ON s.id = g.student
LEFT JOIN t_groups gr
    ON s.group_id = gr.id
LEFT JOIN t_references ref
    ON ref.author = s.id
LEFT JOIN t_program prog
    ON gr.id = prog.group_id
LEFT JOIN t_disciplines dis
    ON prog.discipline_id = dis.code
GROUP BY s.id
ORDER BY s.registration_time DESC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use group by (and should be enough a single group_concat)

```
select CONCAT(data, ' (',  GROUP_CONCAT(another SEPARATOR ', '), ');') as InOneCell
from my_table  
group by data
```

or you could use a subquery

```
select data, group_concat(my_group)
from (
  select data, group_concat(another) my_group 
  group by data
) t 
group by data
```

in your case 
You could use a subquery eg:

```
  SELECT  
  s.name, 
  s.surname, 
  gr.number AS 'group', 
  s.bitrh_date, 
  s.email, 
  s.registration_ip,
  s.registration_time,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT(dis.code, ' ', dis.title, ' (', t.learning, ')') SEPARATOR ';\r\n ') as learning,
  t.average,
  gr.semester,
  ref.text AS reference

  FROM t_students s
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT
    student, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT mark SEPARATOR ', ') learning,
    ROUND(AVG(mark), 2) AS average
    from t_grades
    group by student
    ) t on t.student = s.id
  LEFT JOIN t_groups gr
      ON s.group_id = gr.id
  LEFT JOIN t_references ref
      ON ref.author = s.id
  LEFT JOIN t_program prog
      ON gr.id = prog.group_id
  LEFT JOIN t_disciplines dis
      ON prog.discipline_id = dis.code

  GROUP BY s.id
  ORDER BY s.registration_time DESC
```

Comment: I've already used group by on another key because the table in question joined to the main table. I use group by on row id of main table. Added full query

Comment: answer updated  with a suggestion  ... hope is useful

Comment: Oh I didn't know SQL supported subquery in SELECT :0
Thanks!

Comment: Cool! Apparently I was misguided by wrong source. Thanks for information!

Answer (score 2):

I guess you can try this, just only use `GROUP_CONCAT` once, and add `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT CONCAT(data,'(',GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT another),');')
FROM T
group by data
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/61eb95/2)